# Chrome and Firefox render ::after differently

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

[image: chrome_render]

As you can see there are some problems with the rendering in chrome. And only on some of the list items.

Can someone give me some suggestions on whats happening.

```
&:after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: url('');
  color: transparent;
  background: $blue;
  height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Please put up a reproducible example, this will include relevant HTML so we can run the snippet and see the problem for ourselves, there is not enough in your current code to see the problem. For example, what are you positioning in relation to? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: cant exceed a certain amount of code.  Can setup a github repo if interested. I'm more interested in why it could be happening. Is there some rule about using ::after that I am not aware of.

Comment: You should be able to put up a simple example with a list which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have put Html file, too.
By the way check if the parent of this element contains "**position: relative**" or not?
And you don't need to set a margin value for it

Comment: The parent is `display: flex;`.  I'm halfway through rewriting the styling, so don't need a solution. I was just wondering why there are differences between chrome and ff.